# With Perforce, How to merge files between different streams?

Tags: perforce

all

I got two streams such as Main and Dev. If I worked on Main and modified a file, called move.cs, for solving a problem, how can I merge move.cs to Dev. Since probably I have to change a lot of files on Main stream for correcting errors, it could be easy if the corrected files can be merged or copied to Dev stream, so that the same error can be solved on Dev stream, too.

Is there anyway to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that Dev is the child stream of Main.

From P4V graphical stream view, you can right click on the child stream, and select "Merge/Integrate to Dev...". By default it will try to merge from the parent stream up to parent #head revision.

More generally you have to use the `p4 integrate` command.

Comment: Does it merge every file from Main to Dev? What I need is just merging several files from Main to Dev.

Comment: Have a look here : http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_integrate.html  The command line or GUI takes a number of option. Generally the unit you want to merge in Perforce is a changelist, i.e. a coherent set of changes, but you have the option to select a files or files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also shelf you changset in and unself it in another stream.